# node-sass and python ERROR during npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, sass

I cannot run a project, here is the console log, could you please help me?
It seems there is an issue with node-sass and Python...
How can the node-sass URL be 404... I do not know where I should configure this

```
$ npm install

> node-sass@4.10.0 install C:\SOURCES\menuentite\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.10.0/win32-x64-72_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.10.0/win32-x64-72_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
    try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

    export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

    npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall C:\SOURCES\menuentite\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\SOURCES\menuentite\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\SOURCES\\menuentite\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
```

[...]

```
install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-cookie-service@10.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@^10.0.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-cookie-service@10.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^10.0.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsickle@0.34.3 requires a peer of typescript@~3.3.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN The package tslib is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.10.0 (node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\node-sass):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

audited 1341 packages in 8.257s

1 package is looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 2930 vulnerabilities (2168 low, 11 moderate, 749 high, 2 critical)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Comment: In package.json I should change the version to replace `"node-sass": "^4.14.1",` by the latest version... But still the same 404 error... HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did, I'm not sure what solved the issue, but now it is working:

- Install Python
  Download and install python for windows (accept the option to add to PATH) from:  https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ Add python folder to your PATH, the one to python/python39. I also added an other variable names **python2** in my own windows env variables
- re Install Nodejs then execut the following commandes:

  - npm link @angular/cli
  - npm rebuild node-sass
  - npm --add-python-to-path='true' --debug install --global windows-build-tools
  - npm install --global node-gyp

Finaly I add a new package.json file into my lib projet:

```
{
   "name": "menuT",
    "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

And at the end, I was able to execute the last commande:

```
ng build menuT
```

ouf I'm save...

Comment: Why I have to install Python ?